# Iteration through ListMultimap by key

Tags: java, guava

stackoverflow comunity, I cannot devise how to iterate through `fileToPackageMaping` ListMultimap (Google Guava).

Code:

```
private static ListMultimap<ListMultimap<String, String>, String> fileToPackageMaping = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Map.Entry<ListMultimap<String,String>, Collection<String>> dirMaping : fileToPackageMaping.asMap().entrySet()) {

        ListMultimap<String, String> packageCatalogue = dirMaping.getKey();

        for (String packageName : packageCatalogue.asMap().keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Package :" + packageName);
            System.out.println("Catalogue :" + packageCatalogue.get(packageName));
        }

        Collection<String> urls = dirMaping.getValue();
        for(String url : urls) {
        System.out.println("Url :" + url);
        }
}
```

`packageCatalogue` contains with the same keys, but with different values, so I want to iterate through it in such format (I want to write all specific key values and when print it out) :

`key1, value1, value2, value3.`

`key2, value5, value6.`

At the moment it outputs:

`key1, value1`

`key1, value2`

`key1, value3`

`key2, value5`

`key2, value6`

I hope you understand what i want to do..

Comment: Using `Multimap` as a key in another (multi)map is a very bad idea and probably not what you want. Tell us what you want exactly and what's your use case.

Comment: I want to write three values into ListMultimap with the same keys, for example: dir1, catalogue1, urlLink1; dir2, catalogue2, urlLink2. and when I want to do a little bit sorting of them, which I wrote above.

Comment: Xaerxess, thanks for your observation, I swaped the elements (`ListMultimap<String, ListMultimap<String, String>> fileToPackageMaping = ArrayListMultimap.create();`) and now I got the the desired result.

Comment: @elkoo you should post your solution as an answer and accept it, that will mark the question as closed and may help future visitors to this page

Comment: ok, but at the moment I cannot post here, need to wait a bit, due to the lack of the rights.

Comment: @elkoo surely you can answer your own question now?